# Three IPs on a single computer

Tags: networking

I have got three IPs on my computers, what are they and what is their purpose.
For instance when I Check IP address of my computer by using ipconfig/all, I have following two IPs:
(1) Ethernet adapter Ethernet: 10.1.1.1
Ethernet adapter Npcap Loopback Adapter: 125.16.1.1

But, when I check my IP online using https://whatismyipaddress.com/
I get 144.138.32.1

These many IPs on a single computer,
Confused about their use, plz help.

Comment: *But, when I check my IP online* then you obtain your ISP's external address. That's norma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ethernet Adapter is your physical adapter where the Ethernet cable is plugged and the router you are connecting is configured to give you an IP-Address. This is the address with which your computer can be located in the network (10.1.1.1 or 192.168.x.x).

The NPCAP Loopback Adapter is used for doing network analysis with programms like wireshark. If you don't use it, it can be deactivated.

The address you got from whatismyip is your global address. With this address you can be reached all over the globe.

Comment: `With this address you can be reached all over the globe` That may or may not be true.

Answer (score 5):

> Ethernet adapter Ethernet: 10.1.1.1

This is the LAN or "private" IP address that belongs to the computer itself, and is usable withi the LAN only. The "Ethernet adapter" is your wired LAN port.

> when I check my IP online using https://whatismyipaddress.com/ I get 144.138.32.1

This is the "public" IP address that belongs to your router, and is usable for the entire Internet. Your ISP only gives you one public address, so all your devices must share it – all connections made through the router appear as if they were made using the router's address.

> Ethernet adapter Npcap Loopback Adapter: 125.16.1.1

This is a virtual adapter installed by Wireshark, to provide the ability to monitor "localhost" connections. For some reason it seems to have address that's officially owned by Bharti Airtel, but it's probably something Wireshark developers left in by accident. In any case, even though this address is also configured on your computer, the Npcap adapter isn't actually used for network access.